# Why regex_match() and regex_search() do not work?

Tags: c++, regex

my data file (m;w,t,w,t,w,t......,w,t) is like :

> 5762;895,360851.301667
>
> 5763;895,360851.301667
>
> 83495;166,360817.861111
>
> 175040156;7597,360815.840556,6905,363521.083889,774,363647.044722,20787,364348.666667,3158,364434.308333,3702,364480.726944,8965,365022.092778,1071,365043.283333,82,365544.150000,9170,365607.336667,46909,365635.057778,2165,365754.650000,895,366683.907500,121212,366689.450000,10571,366967.131944,1499,367707.580833,1790,368741.724167,7715,369115.480000
>
> .........

and I want to find lines with (w,t) pairs occured >=7 times. I used this code:

```
ofstream MyTxtFile;
ifstream file("ipod-cascades.txt");
MyTxtFile.open("ipod-res.txt");
bool isWebId = true;
int n = 7,count=0;
string line;
string value;
smatch m;
while (getline(file, line)){
    if (std::regex_search(line,m, std::regex(";([^,]*,[^,]*,){7,}"))){
        
        count++;
        std::stringstream  linestream(line);
        std::string  tmp;


        if (getline(linestream, value, ';')){
        
            while (getline(linestream, tmp, ',')){

                if (isWebId){
                    MyTxtFile << value << "," << tmp;

                    isWebId = false;
                }
                else{
                    MyTxtFile << "," << tmp << endl;
                    isWebId = true;


                }
            }
        }
    }

    }
```

when I use 'regex_match()' it does not find any line, and when I use 'regex_search()' it finds some lines and then gives stackoverflow exception.what is the problem with my code?
by the way, I'm using VS2013.

Comment: What compiler is this? Remember: newer gcc don't support regex fully for now. Use Boost! Boost will work.

Comment: post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @rubberboots i think this is the main problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regex is not fully supported in the newer gcc. I used regular expression in terminal and made a new file:

```
 grep -E ";([^,]*,[^,]*,){7,}" file.txt>>res.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::regex_match` will only return `true` if the *entire* string matches the pattern. That is, there must not be any characters neither before nor after the expression you want to match. Use `std::regex_search` for matching a partial string.

Why `std::regex_search` gives stack overflow is not easy to see from your code excerpt. Most likely the error is a result of the processing you do if you find a match rather than from the library, though. Spin it through the debugger, and you'll quickly see the cause of the stack overflow.

Comment: I edited the code. see above!   the exception is:  Unhandled exception at 0x774BDF3E (ntdll.dll) in code.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x00272FEC).

Comment: What line does the debugger tell you the exception is from?

Comment: if (std::regex_search(line,m, std::regex(";([^,]*,[^,]*,){7,}")))